# question in Boolean algebra?

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra, karnaugh-map

the question states: (Using Boolean Algebra; show that the following equation is valid: 
       A'BC'D+(A'+BC)(A+C'D')+BC'D+A'BC' = ABCD+A'C'D'+ABD+ABCD'+BC'D

RHS and using de Morgan law 
A'BC'D+(A'+BC)'+(A+C'D')'+BC'D+A'BC'
A'BC'D+A'B'C'+A'CD+ABC'D+A'BC'D' 
and from there i cant find a way to present it in LHS form since both are 5 terms each its not simplifying

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, and where you are getting stuck. We don't do your homework for you

Comment: Draw truth tables of the LHS and the RHS and see they are the same.

Comment: yes but the question states that only using Boolean algebra so no truth table or karnaugh map

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please quickly realise that this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows that you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which your post doesn't, I'm afraid. Please revise your question showing your work and findings so far, in considerable detail. Or delete the question if Internet searches give you your answer anyway. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: you really do not see any similarities in these 5 terms? ..............`A'BC'D+A'B'C'+A'CD+ABC'D+A'BC'D'` .... try putting them in a column, one on each of 5 lines

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- Work on LHS and RHS separately, simplifying parentheses and bringing them to a general SP form, i.e. sum of products. For example ACD + ABCD + B'C.
- For each product try to expand it to a *minterm*, i.e. a product containing all the variables. The usual trick is to use the identity X+X'=1. For example: ACD=A(1)CD=A(B+B')CD=ABCD+AB'CD. 
  Note that for each application of this trick you get two products with one more variable. Repeat until you get products with *all* variables in them (either normal or negated).
- When every product on both sides match you are done.

Note: this is not an optimized procedure, but it works always.